# Formal languages. What is the definition of $L^*L^*$?

Tags: formal-languages

I need to use it to prove $L^*=L^*L^*$.

So I know that $L^*=L^1 \cup L^2 \cup L^3\cup\ldots$

But how do you describe $L^* L^*$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $L^*=L^0\cup L^1\cup L^2\cup  ...$?. If you have two languages $A,B$ there definition of $AB$ is $\{ab\mid\ a\in A,\ b\in B\}$. This same 'multiplication' is what you use to define $L^0=\{\epsilon\}$ and inductively $L^{n+1}=LL^{n}$.

Comment: To prove $L^*\subset L^*L^*$ take an arbitrary $w\in L^*$. Since $w=w\epsilon$ and $w\in  L^*$ and $\epsilon\in L^*$, we get that $w=w\epsilon\in L^*L^*$. For the inclusion $L^*L^*\subset L^*$ take $w\in L^*L^*$. Then, there are $a,b\in L^*$ such that $w=ab$. Since $a,b\in L^*$, there are $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a\in L^m,b\in L^n$. It follows that $ab\in L^{m+n}$. Here we used that $L^mL^n=L^{m+n}$, a little lemma that you can prove by induction. Then $w=ab\in L^{m+n}\subset L^*$.